# Vertically center a-href element within fully clickable responsive list-item

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Does anyone know how to **vertical center** a-href elements in list-items while keeping them responsive and the whole list element clickable?

I've tried various things: vertical-align, display:table/table-cell etcetera, googled a lot and searched stack overflow, but none of the solutions seem to work (or I'm just implementing them wrong) or cover all the issues (center, clickable, responsive). The list item's height is reacting to the height of the browser, because of the display div (which is going to display a photo and I don't want to lose details because of the two menu items that cover it).

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K6V58/1/

HTML:

```
    <div id="wrapper">
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>    
            <li><a href="#">test 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <article id="display">boe</article>
    <nav id="gallery">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/klein/square.jpg" class="imageList"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/klein/square.jpg" class="imageList"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*---------------------------- MAIN MENU ----------------------------*/
#wrapper{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

nav#menu, nav#menu ul, nav#menu ul li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  

    font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:10pt;
    color:grey;

    background-color:#000000;
}

nav#menu{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:5%;
    text-align:right;
}

nav#menu ul{
    padding: 0 10px;
    height:100%;
}

nav#menu ul li{
    height:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
    list-style: none;
}

nav#menu ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:grey;
    height:100%;
    display: block;
}

/*---------------------------- IMAGE MENU ----------------------------*/


nav#gallery, nav#gallery ul, nav#gallery ul li, img.imageList{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
    background-color:#000000;
}

nav#gallery{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:5%;
}

nav#gallery ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}

.imageList{
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:top;
}

/*---------------------------- DISPLAY PHOTO ----------------------------*/

article#display{
    position:absolute;
    top:5%;
    width:100%;
    height:90%;
    background-image:url(../images/gallery/groot/2.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: could you update your fiddle with fake image from http://lorempixel.com or http://dummyimage.com (they can be sized), so we can see what really happens or not :)

Comment: @GCyrillus Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K6V58/1/  
The big image isn't the issue by the way, just the menu items. :)

Comment: you could use a pseudo element to increase width of <a>. http://jsfiddle.net/K6V58/2/

Comment: It isn't centering in the fiddle?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/K6V58/4/)

Comment: Well, kinda, but not quite. It uses margin in px, which isn't responsive because when the browser is smaller it'll fall out of the black parent div. And I want the menu bar in the top of the browser, not in the center ;)

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/K6V58/6/)?

Comment: @Tushar I think that works! Please post it as answer so I can accept it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/K6V58/6/)

I have added `span` inside `a`
HTML

```
<li><a href="#"><span>test 1</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>test 2</span></a></li>
```

And updated this CSS

```
nav#menu ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:grey;
    height:100%;
    display: table;
}
nav#menu ul li a span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle
}
```